# php regex form questions

Tags: php

Is it possible to just use this code alone to do two different regex matches?

One reg-ex match for X digits and the other for a given string "CAT" only, or do I need to create two different forms, one for each: X digits and one for the string "CAT"?

Furthermore is there a better php method for this or I am headed in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

```
<form action ="callself.php" method = "post">
 Enter a numeric value:
<br/>
<input type = "text" name = "number"/>
<br /><br />
<input type = "submit"/>
<br /><br />
</form>
```

I am a newb(still in the process of learning, thank you in advance for not flaming)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so you're trying to match either "CAT" or any number of digits from $_POST['number']? What do you want returned if a) x number of digits are matched c) CAT is matched?

Comment: Sorry I  did not clarify, I just split the form into two chunks one for the digits to be matched via regex that uses the variable number and the other form uses the variable string to regex match  CAT, sorry about that.  I only posted one aspect of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if the field contanins either `CAT` or a sequence of digit, you can use this check:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:CAT|\d+)$/', $field))
```

if you need to act differently in the two cases, explain better.

Comment: I guess, using the above method, I might as well just remove the second form I had created, thank you.